# ionic ngx-dropzone Option to hide the Take a picture IOS

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, ngx-drag-drop

In Ionic I am using ngx-dropzone to upload the file. Its working fine in Web and mobile(IOS and Android) applications. But problem here, In IOS while clicking that file upload area showing three dropdown option. In that option **Take a Picture** need to remove. If any have idea or facing same issue please give me suggestion. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a parameter `capture="false"` in `ngx-dropzone` html element.
https://docs.dropzone.dev/configuration/basics/configuration-options